# Does VTD-XML allow complex xpath expressions?

Tags: xml, xpath, contains, concatenation, vtd-xml

I've been using VTD-XML to run xpath expressions but I have found that any XPath expression more complicated than using a file type address (i.e. //Books/authors) breaks down and simply resorts to returning the entire file.

I have two examples one using the concat() method the other using the contains() method.

My **test.xml** document:

```
<a>
  <b>The</b>
  <c>fox</c>
  <d>
    <e>jumps</e>
  </d>
</a>
```

***First Issue***

I am having an issue when running a concatenation like so:

```
concat(//b, ' ', //c, ' ', '- Found: ', \"'\", //d/e, \"'\")
```

This should return:

```
The fox - Found: 'jumps'
```

but instead returns:

```
Thefoxjumps Thefoxjumps - Found: 'Thefoxjumps'
```

***VTD Used for First Issue***

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/../test.xml");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
byte[] b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
fis.read(b);

VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(b);
vg.parse(true);
VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
ap.selectXPath("concat(//b, ' ', //c, ' ', '- Found: ', \"'\", //d/e, \"'\")");

System.out.println(ap.evalXPathToString());
```

***Second Issue***

When I run a contains like this one:

```
//a[contains('|jumps|runs|', d/e)]
```

This should return the "a" tag as there is an "e" tag that contains 'jumps'. But instead this returns nothing.

***VTD Code Used for Second Issue***

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/../test.xml");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
byte[] b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
fis.read(b);

VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(b);
vg.parse(true);
VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
int r;
while((r = ap.evalXPath()) != -1){
    System.out.println("Tag: "+vn.toString(r));
}
```

Comment: plz download the latest jar file when it is released... which is very soon..

Comment: I added the jar to my project but it is still giving me the exact same result. I even tried renaming the jar to 2.12 so that it has the same name as the folder it's in, but nothing changed. Thanks for the parseFile suggestions though, it's much cleaner.

Comment: I think you probably have a global classpath setting issue... your code works fine in my eclipse environment...do you run it in eclipse or on command prompt?

Comment: I'm running it on Eclipse Mars

Comment: so I set the classpath as so; "set classpath=C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\ximpleware-2.12-java\vtd-xml.jar;C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\ximpleware-2.12-java\vtd-xml_2.13.jar;.;" Then I navigated to where my testvtd.java file was and ran it as so "javac testvtd.java" followed by "java testvtd". I made sure to include the new jar file you sent me to the ximpleware folder, which is why it was named vtd-xml_2.13.jar. But I still got the exact same result :( Any thoughts?

Comment: That worked!! haha thanks! but, then why are the two jars included in the download file?

Comment: 2 jars? No, that is not the case.... someone likely erred while editing the class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first issue, I ran the query on the latest build... it returns

```
The fox - Found: 'jumps'
```

It appears that this is unfortunately a bug introduced in 2.12 that has been reported and fixed... notice that it should work correctly in 2.10 or 2.11

go to http://vtd-xml.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vtd-xml/ximple-dev/com/ximpleware/LocationPathExpr.java?revision=1.64 and download the file and 
build a jar yourself using the build.bat script bundled with the distribution...

I also ran the second test on the latest build (slated for 2.13) it works fine and returns a single node...

They appear to relate to the same bug...

Comment: So I have replaced the LocationPathExpr.java file in my copy of the Ximpleware folder than after configuring my PATH to run javac and jar, I ran the build.bat file which updated the "vtd-xml-2-12.jar" jar. I then copied that into my working folder and ran the code but it still gave me the exact same result.

Comment: did you remove the old jar and replace it with a new jar? If that does not work Let me do a build on my end and put up a jar for you to download soon... will give you a URL link, it will be pretty much v2.13 head of scheduled release

Comment: Yea I removed the old jar from my working directory I didn't delete the one from the Ximpleware folder. however, one of the jars was modified. Yes I would really appreciate that! Thank you!